# Repeated getOrElse for when value is None or function's result is None

Tags: scala

Given:

```
val x = Option(1) // or None
def f(p: Int) = Option("a") // or None
val Default = "b"
```

This code:

```
x.map(i => f(i).getOrElse(Default)).getOrElse(Default)
```

is working as designed.

Is there a way to avoid repeating the `getOrElse(Default)` in the code? Rules: 1. code is shorter than the above, or at least clearer/more readable, 2. run `f` only once, and 3. the first three "given" lines of code can't change (if that's not clear already :)

With many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.flatMap(f).getOrElse(Default)
```